# I don't feel anxious on stage, but I perform badly

Tags: stage-fright

I never thought myself to have stage fright. I never feel anxious or scared about performing. However, when I get on stage my performance is suddenly horrible. Easy songs become impossible. How do I stop this?

Comment: Some more detail may help to get the answer you are looking for. Do you perform with others or by yourself? What do you mean with: "my performance is suddenly horrible"? Horrible how? Do you forget the music, forget how to play your instrument, lose all sense of rhythm, lose the ability to control dynamics...?

Answer (score 5):

Practice with distractions.  Practice while observing yourself in a mirror.  Practice while keeping a camera rolling.  Practice while trying to learn a poem.  If your instrument does not require your breath and voice, *recite* a poem while playing.

The problem is that with your usual practice, your concentration is on your play and the setup is 100% under your control and what you are accustomed to.

Play before an audience, and 30% of your focus are concerned dealing with audience and stage.  If the remaining 70% are fine for working your instrument and you can consequently cater to the audience and adapt to it, you'll be better than a recording to them.  Which is more or less the point of an actual performance.

Do not expect things to work that are at the limit of your sovereignty when practising on them on your own.  You don't want to merely prove to your audience that stuff is at the level you manage.  You want to hand them something, and if what you carry is too heavy, you'll just fall over when stretching out your hands.

Answer (score 0):

Not everyone gets nervous.  Personally, I can't imagine not being nervous because music is very challenging to master.  I might say impossible.  That being said, I have advanced my performance ability considerably by learning to have laser focus on what I'm doing.  This is equal parts control and letting go.  With nothing in your mind but listening and letting the music flow through you.  As soon as you think about what your fingers are doing, you're not focusing.  If you must think about what your fingers are doing, you must practice more until it is second nature.  Seeing a masterful performance is special because it's not about the person performing it, but the music they brought to life.  But performance is not just for the virtuosos of the world, it is for everyone.